# The use of ''riddle' in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Harry kept quiet. He did not want to express the doubts and uncertainties about Dumbledore that had **riddled** him for months now.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I feel 'riddle' here is used metaphorically, because I don't expect it would  pierce Harry with numerous holes. What does 'riddle' mean exactly?

Comment: There are two definitions of "riddle", the one you found doesn't apply in this context, as you have noticed xD

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Contrary to most answers here, I think there are mutiple meanings here.

> Doubts about Dumbledore had riddled him

You could argue (as others have) that the doubts he had about Dumbledore were puzzling to Harry.

However, unless Dumbledore actually set him some riddles/puzzles to solve, I think it really means that Harry is:

> Riddled with doubt

This is a metaphorical usage of being filled with something - This implies that he had many doubts and uncertainties that he was struggling with.

See [Merriam Webster definition of riddle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riddle):

> 3: to spread through :
>       permeate a book riddled with errors

Comment: This is the best answer; the use of "riddled" with "doubt" certainly invokes this idiom, and the sentence definitely reads either way.

Comment: @BadZen Is it a pun intended here?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: To me it seems unambiguous if I pay attention: It's not "Dumbledore that had riddled him" - it's "the doubts that had riddled him" where the doubts are about Dumbledore.

Comment: As a native speaker of British English, this is my instinctive reading of the sentence.  I notice that most of the answers disagreeing with this appear to be from speakers of American English - as such, I wonder if "riddled with doubt" is an idiom less familiar in the USA?

Comment: I'm Am.E, and while this isn't the sort of question that can be definitively answered with "it's not, of course", I'd place a wager on more than 80% of randomly sampled Am.E speakers recognizing the idiom and agreeing with your reading.   It certainly occurs in both sets of dialects.

Comment: What's strange is that in the [Cambs Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riddled) it puts this definition as AmE (book riddled with errors) but I recognise it with the same instinct as @Chronocidal

Comment: Taking my cue from Smock and BadZen, I was half-way editing my answer, but realized the only thing I wanted to add is that I consider this a *convergent evolution* of two homonyms. But that is not really what OP is interested in hearing. So I simply threw in the towel and upvoted the best answer. Great question too.

Comment: I strongly suspect, as Chronocidal's comment implies, that the answers that give the puzzle definition were written by people not familiar with the idiom.  As a native AmE speaker, I also echo BadZen's that it is a well known idiom AmE too.

Comment: @BadZen Given the importance of the name Riddle in the story, how can we not read it as a pun?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Because “riddle” is far too common a word to assume that Rowling’s every use of it is a pun on that character, no matter how important he is. I might read it as a pun (intentional or otherwise) if the doubts had been about that character, or if it weren’t for the common phrase “riddled with doubts” that leads us to expect that particular word rather than a synonym, but as it is, no.

Comment: Anyway, seems unnecessary to beat a dead horse at this point, but I’ll confirm that “riddled with doubts” is common in Am.E. and that as a native Am.E. speaker this is also how I read things here.

Answer (score -1):

The noun "riddle" is a kind of verbal puzzle, and there is a corresponding verb with the primary meaning of posing such a puzzle. So there is no reference here to the verb "riddle" with the meaning of "pierce." Instead, the meaning is simply that doubts had puzzled Harry. In my part of the U.S., this usage of "riddle" as a verb where a situation rather than a human is the riddler is rare enough to be quite odd, but it may be common elsewhere. Nevertheless, the usage would be comprehensible to almost any native speaker.

Comment: There is a reference to the idiom "riddled with doubt", which does not imply "puzzled".

Comment: *"doubts had puzzled Harry"* - this essentially means Harry is confused, which he is. Can someone explain the downvotes? I don't get how this answer is soooo outrageous to merit 3 downvotes. Since when have we started to downvote less than perfect answers? Is this answer perfect? No. Is it wrong? No. Is it partially correct and useful? Yes. If you hover over the downvote arrow, it says "this answer is not useful". It is useful. The highly upvoted answer also says this is one meaning. I honestly don't get it. But I want to hear and understand why this answer is so bad.

Comment: @AIQ Is it wrong? *Yes.* Refer to Smock's answer which references Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @Adeptus To me both answers are pointing out the same thing. Smock's answer just does it in a better way. Can you tell me which part in Jeff's answer is wrong? Smock's answer cover Jeff's answer too.

Comment: Jeff says it means "puzzle". The pertinent part of Smock's answer says it means "filled with" or "spread through", which arises from the same root meaning as "pierced" - a riddle being a sieve; being riddled with holes; being riddled with <something else>.

Comment: @Adeptus Jeff wrote *"Instead, the meaning is simply that **doubts had puzzled Harry**."* Jeff did not say "riddle means puzzle".

Comment: How is he **not** saying "riddle means puzzle"? *"The noun "riddle" is a kind of verbal **puzzle**, and there is a corresponding verb with the primary meaning of posing such a **puzzle**. ...doubts had **puzzled** Harry."* The original quote was "doubts ... had *riddled* him".

Answer (score -4):

True! It's in the sense of *puzzling* the character.

Check the verb version here in [this dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/riddled) -

> *A question or statement requiring thought to answer or understand; a conundrum.*

It's an entry for *v. rid·dled, rid·dling, rid·dles*